# Java: ReplaceAll String with another string

Tags: java, javascript, string

I'm relatively new to this...

I'm trying to perform replace.all that will replace all instances of "PRICING" in a string with a numerical value which is also a variable: PRICE

```
SUBSCRIPTION = SUBSCRIPTION.replaceAll("PRICING",PRICE);
```

Below is the error i get.

```
Error in method invocation: Method replaceAll( java.lang.String, double ) not found in class'java.lang.String'
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: And the problem is... ?

Comment: your code is ok!.. PRICE is String right?

Comment: Can you please provide your problem as well..many thanks..

Comment: Sorry I probably should have clarified my error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SUBSCRIPTION = SUBSCRIPTION.replaceAll("PRICING", String.valueOf(PRICE));
```

Comment: There it is! thanks so much I'm still learning this helped a ton.

Answer (score 1):

PRICE need to be STRING not double.

You can try this:

```
String price = String.valueOf(PRICE)
SUBSCRIPTION = SUBSCRIPTION.replaceAll("PRICING",price);
```

Comment: I see thanks! so  maybe I should spend some more time learning about strings etc. i'm just having trouble constructing the price variable so that it is a string rather than a double?

Comment: @user1629055  It was a pleasure to help you :D!! you can now check the answer correct!

Comment: @user1629055 - Leave `price` as `double` (especially, if you use it for calculations).

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll()` needs the input as,

```
public String replaceAll(String regex,
                String replacement)
```

so the replacement should be the `string` here , not the `double` as your error says,

```
 Error in method invocation: Method replaceAll( java.lang.String, double)
```

convert it into `String`  using `valueOf()` method . or ,

```
String price= Double.toString(PRICE);
```

Learn more on [`String#replaceAll()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) method

Answer (score 0):

```
String pricing = MessageFormat.format("{0, number, currency}", PRICE);

SUBSCRIPTION = SUBSCRIPTION.replaceAll("PRICING", pricing);
```

Must be a string.

Here I use the default Locale with MessageFormat.

Furthermore: BigDecimal might be a better choice than the lossy double. BigDecimal must use methods like `add` but double is just an approximation of a real number.

Answer (score 0):

The variable PRICE is of type double, and the method replaceAll requires second parameter to be a String. Just add the conversion:

```
SUBSCRIPTION = SUBSCRIPTION.replaceAll("PRICING",String.valueOf(PRICE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work fine.

```
SUBSCRIPTION = SUBSCRIPTION.replaceAll("PRICING",String.valueOf(PRICE));
```

Answer (score 0):

As is indicated by the error message the replaceAll() method takes two string arguments. Try using "String.valueOf(PRICE)" to convert your double to a String representation.